# Waiting for several players' input

Tags: android, dialog

I am making a game in which certain events require every player to input their reaction, out of the normal game flow. For example, with 4 human players, four dialogs will pop-up in a row to ask each player what they want to do. This is the only way I found to wait for the input.

```
int counter = 0;

void askInput() {
  counter++;
  if (counter > max)
    return;
  // initialize dialog
  AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);                  
  builder.setTitle(R.string.title)
  .setNegativeButton(R.string.button, new OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
           askInput();
         }                          
  });
  AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
  dialog.show();
}
```

This seems sketchy to me. What would be the Android way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after reflection it doesn't seem so sketchy.